# Google Login popup blocked in older browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, google-signin

I have an Ionic app which can be served for mobile device or as a web app, there is a button which allows google login, and depending on whether its a web app or a native app google login works differently, only mention this because otherwise we could use the more standard google login button.

So the web app login works on all current browsers, and in Chrome without a popup, but in older browsers (notably Chrome 43 and 44) it tries to open a popup which is then blocked by Chrome.

I am using the Google Javascript Api (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) for web app login and should be able to provide options to change the popup to show the user a page instead, but this seems to be ignored. After a bit of commenting out it appears to be the '_gapi.signIn' function that is causing the popup not the init.

Our code is as below:

```
gapi.load (
    'auth2',
        () => {
            if (!_gapi) {
                _gapi = gapi.auth2.init ({
                 client_id : credentials.clientId,
                 cookiepolicy : 'single_host_origin',
            })
        }

        _gapi.signIn ({
            display : 'page',
            prompt : 'none',
        }).then (
            (gUser) => {
                let profile
                profile = gUser.getBasicProfile ()
                resolve (profile.getEmail ())
            },

            () => reject ('Google connection error')
        )
    }
)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, cheers!